# remove marginBottom from slds-card__body class on lightning-datatable lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, slds

We are using lightning-datatable. lightning-datatable has slds-card__body class. marginBottom is part of slds-card__body class.

I want to make marginBottom zero. I try the below code but it did not work for me.

[image]

```
:host {
    --sds-c-card__body-margin-bottom: 0;
    --sds-c-card-body-margin-bottom: 0;
    --slds-c-card-body-margin-bottom: 0;
    --slds-c-card__body-margin-bottom: 0;
}
.slds-card__body {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we have to override CSS of standard lwc component :

Create a CSS file and add in static resource
File Content :

```
.slds-card__body {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Import That static resource file in your component

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CUSTOMCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/{yourfileName}';
```

a) Define variable like : isCssLoaded = false;

Call it in reRenderCallback

```
renderedCallback(){

if(this.isCssLoaded) return
this.isCssLoaded = true;
loadStyle(this,CUSTOMCSS).then(()=>{
    console.log('loaded');
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log('error to load');
});
}
```